# Java: null comparison always yields false: incorrect warning?

Tags: java, zip, warnings, outputstream

Interesting situation.  I have a section of code that creates several ZipOutputStreams.  As a safety check before I even think about writing anything I check thta my output streams have been correctly initialised:

```
ZipOutputStream countStream = null;
File countFile = null;
// other files

try {
    countFile =
    new File(savePath.getCanonicalPath() + savePath.separator + outputTag
        + "_COUNT_OUTPUTS.zip");
    // other files
} catch (Exception e) {
    outputLog.add("UNABLE TO FIND SAVE PATH");
    return util.FILE_INVALID;
}

try {
    // prepare outputs
    if (countFile.exists() == true) {
    countFile.delete();
    } else {
    }
    countStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(countFile));
    // other files
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    outputLog.add("UNABLE TO CREATE OUTPUT FILES");
    return util.FILE_SAVE_FAIL;
}

if (countStream == null) {
    outputLog.add("UNABLE TO CREATE OUTPUT FILES");
    return util.FILE_SAVE_FAIL;
} else {
}
```

I dont especially see where the problem is in this code, but it throws up a warning on the null test: "Null comparison always yields false: The variable countStream cannot be null at this location".  As far as I can see it, I have a variable initialised to null, then the creation of an outputstream is attempted, but isn't guaranteed to happen.  ignoring the warning is easy enough, but I'd rather know how the compiler comes to the conclusion that countStream is guaranteed to be successfully created

K.Barad

Comment: if countstream is not null it will return false. whats wrong with that?

Comment: Your error message refers to timeStream not countStream. Is that a copy paste error?

Comment: By the way you should add a finally block to the try catch that istanciates the ZipOutputStream to close it (calling the close() method)).

Comment: By the way: in `if (countFile.exists() == true)` the `== true` part is superfluous

Comment: @Richard: well caught, yeah I've got several zips, all with the identical warning.

Comment: @Sean: I know, as are my else{} blocks, but I've always believed that being explicit in such things is the safest option and helps filter out stupid mistakes (common on Friday mornings)

Comment: @K.Barad the point is: in Java, as opposed to C, for example, this kind of stupid mistakes is impossible :-)

Comment: @reef: the section for closing is separate, I have quite a large number of outputs with various options, and I prefer to keep my try-catch fairly atomic rather than encompassing a whole 300 line function.  I do flush (since I wrap it in a printwriter later) and close my streams though.

Comment: @Sean: as much as I hate to admit it, after a month of deep focus in an application until my eyesight turns to ascii, there is no limit to how stupid the mistakes can get when they happen.

Comment: @K.Barad I am not saying you won't make the mistakes. Everybody makes stupid mistakes. I'm saying the Java compiler won't allow you to make them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is able to see that you cannot be null there since:

1. in your `try` you've initialized it (`countStream = new ....`) and
2. in your `catch` you've "`return`"ed out of the method.

Hence, the code "`if (countStream == null)`" can only be attained through normal flow after `countStream` has been initialized to a non-null `ZipOutputStream`.

Comment: This is one of the cases where the compiler can do some great path checking.  The error, as the answerer claimed is simply "It can't be null here".  You misinterpreted the answer as "a null comparasion always returns false".  (I didn't know if Kelindil was clear enough about that--too polite perhaps :) )

Comment: I had a suspicion it was something along these lines.  Is this to say I'm just being redundantly cautious, and that FileOutputStream and ZipOutputStream are safe enough to not need any more checking than the try-catch blocks?

Comment: a "new ..." instantiation, whatever the constructor you are calling, on whichever class, can not return null. It can fail in various exceptions, but cannot be null. Thus this null check is indeed redundant : you have either instantiated it to a non null value, failed out of the method because of an exception, or returned out of the method through your catch.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up.  I'm still somewhat inexperienced in streams and their wrapping and keep forgetting to see them as objects

Answer (score 5):

When there is no Exception, the variable countStream will not be null. When there is an Exception, you `return util.FILE_SAVE_FAIL` and the null check will not be performed. Hence, whenever the null check is performed, the result will always be false.

Slightly more formal: There are no code paths by which execution can reach your null check that result in `countStream` being null when the check is performed.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from this code is countStream is null and thats why its giving warning that "Null comparison always yields false"

If you debug you will find this code always goes to else part because `if (countStream == null) {` condition does not pass.

Comment: Ummm ... the compiler is saying that the value is NEVER `null`.